# How does Python's reversed() function work?

Tags: python, cpython, python-internals

According to [Python's docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#reversed), `reversed()` uses `__getitem__` and `__len__` if `__reversed__` is not implemented.

I've encountered a weird behavior and failed to explain it:

```
>>> class A(dict):
...     pass
...
>>> reversed(A())
Traceback (most recent call last):
    ...
TypeError: 'A' object is not reversible

>>> class B(dict):
...     def __getitem__(self, key):
...         return super().__getitem__(key)
...     def __len__(self):
...         return super().__len__()
...
>>> reversed(B())
Traceback (most recent call last):
    ...
TypeError: 'B' object is not reversible

>>> class C:
...     def __getitem__(self, key):
...         return "item"
...     def __len__(self):
...         return 1
...
>>> reversed(C())
<reversed object at 0x00000000022BB9B0>
```

Although calling `reversed()` on mapping types makes no sense, how does it know it's a mapping? Does it internally check `isinstance(inst, dict)`? Does it check for any general mapping like `collections.abc.Mapping`? Is there any way to override this behavior without implementing `__reversed__`?

I thought it might be due to `dict` implementing a `__reversed__` that throws a `TypeError`, or one that equals `None` much like how you disable `__hash__`, but `dict.__reversed__` turned out empty with `AttributeError` thrown.

## UPDATE:

New Python versions implement `__reversed__` for dictionaries. Mapping protocols (such as collections.abc.Mapping) set `__reversed__` to `None`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, there's a check for `dict` type in [`PySequence_Check`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/abstract.c#L1508) [used by `reversed`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/55edd0c185ad2d895b5d73e47d67049bc156b654/Objects/enumobject.c#L294).

```
// cpython/Objects/enumobject.c
if (!PySequence_Check(seq)) {
    PyErr_Format(PyExc_TypeError,
                 "'%.200s' object is not reversible",
                 Py_TYPE(seq)->tp_name);
    return NULL;
}


// cpython/Objects/abstract.c

int
PySequence_Check(PyObject *s)
{
    if (PyDict_Check(s))
        return 0;
    return s != NULL && s->ob_type->tp_as_sequence &&
        s->ob_type->tp_as_sequence->sq_item != NULL;
}
```

Comment: I've actually searched for the C implementation, but never thought of looking inside `enumobject.c`. Thank you for that. Any tips for finding builtin functions scattered in the source code?

Comment: @Bharel Builtins are mostly present in [Python/bltinmodule.c](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Python/bltinmodule.c), there you can do a basic search and go ahead from there. For this case you can see that `reversed` points to `PyReversed_Type` and that is present in `enumobject.c`.

Comment: Thank you for that! Last but not least, I'm not sure if you would know, but why would they check specifically for `dict` and not just make `dict` set `__reversed__` to `None`? It seems like a hacky solution that offers no optimization (as lookup for the dunder is done beforehand) .

Comment: @Bharel I think it's a basic way to differentiate between a mapping and sequence, with `dict` check they are sure we have a subclass of `dict` and that case can be handled. In general the chances of defining a custom mapping type are lesser than inheriting from dict and modifying some methods there. Hence, for a dict it will be much common to see `KeyError`s because of people trying to reverse iterate it.

Comment: @Bharel C-API docs for [`PySequence_Check`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/sequence.html#sequence-protocol) say: Note that it returns 1 for Python classes with a `__getitem__()` method unless they are `dict` subclasses since in general case it is impossible to determine what the type of keys it supports. This function always succeeds.

Comment: @Bharel Also check: http://grokbase.com/t/python/python-list/054erpfcep/new-style-classes-iter-and-pysequence-check#20050414oq3okaw2kfbymmfn7ow32enfz4

Answer (score 0):

This function implemented in [PEP-322](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0322/#proposal) via python:

```
def reversed(x):
    if hasattr(x, 'keys'):
        raise ValueError("mappings do not support reverse iteration")
    i = len(x)
    while i > 0:
        i -= 1
        yield x[i]
```

Comment: Mappings can now be iterated in reverse because they're ordered. The iterator only runs through the dict's keys.